# Linq Max with null object and property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I Have flights object list.In this list every flight object has segment object list.Every item in this segment object list has FareDisplayInfos object list.Every FareDisplayInfos object has property such as totalFare

I want to get Max totalFare.So I coded like this.

```
Model.Flights.Max(a => a.FlightSegments.FirstOrDefault().FareDisplayInfos.Max(c => c.TotalFare));
```

But it give zero because some totalFare is null and some value is zero.
How can I eliminate null or zero object
Note:Not only TotalFare is zero or null.Somet times objects such as FareDisplayInfos is null

Edited

With tim-schmelter assistance i code this but it set max to 0 (zero)
although there is 43 item in this( LeaveRouteListAcer) and this items has  FlightSegments that segment has many FareDisplayInfos  and that FareDisplayInfos  has total fare(some fare is 0 some is 90....)

```
 var maxTotalFare = hModel.LeaveList
.SelectMany(f => f.FlightSegments
    .Where(fs => fs != null && fs.FareDisplayInfos != null)
    .Select(fs => fs.FareDisplayInfos.Max(fdi => fdi.TotalFare))
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0))
.Max();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, presuming that `TotalFare` is a nullable:

```
var maxTotalFare = Model.Flights
    .SelectMany(f => f.FlightSegments
        .Where(fs => fs != null && fs.FareDisplayInfos != null)
        .Select(fs => fs.FareDisplayInfos.Max(fdi => fdi.TotalFare ?? 0))
        .DefaultIfEmpty(0))
    .Max();
```

Comment: FareDisplayInfos is object array.So we should use FareDisplayInfos.Firsrt() or any other things

Comment: fdi.TotalFare ?? 0))   in here it give error   Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'int'

Comment: @user1688401: then try `Max(fdi => fdi.TotalFare ?? 0m)`. What type is `TotalFare`?

Comment: it is decimal.I changed 0m and other things it still give that error Error   Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal'

Comment: @user1688401: but you have mentioned that _"some totalFare is null "_. If it was a `decimal` it cannot be `null` but just zero. That's why i thought that it is a `decimal?`. If it's a `decimal` you don't need the null-coalescing-operator but just this: `s.FareDisplayInfos.Max(fdi => fdi.TotalFare)`

Comment: i changed it,but it set max to 0(zero)...I edited question .Please look last paragraph .thanks.

Comment: @user1688401: the code you posted is not even similar to the code i have poosted.

Comment: Sorry @Tim Schamelter ,I posted your code,I edited question again

Answer (score 0):

Just chect it like this with ternary operator.

```
Model.Flights.Max(a => a.FlightSegments == null 
? 0
: a.FlightSegments.FirstOrDefault().FareDisplayInfos == null
   ? 0
   : a.FlightSegments.FirstOrDefault().FareDisplayInfos.Max(c => c.TotalFare == null ? 0 : c.TotalFare)
);
```

Comment: it still  give zero.I think there is problem with FirstOrDefault

Comment: @user1688401 could be =) It's really difficult to understad your db  structure and what you really want to do. But ternary will always helps you when you need to check on null.

Comment: this is not my db,this data come from (bad)service there are many and many objects nested and main parent object can be null